# /?q=#/ in URL Query String?

Tags: php, javascript, url

`/?q=#/` in Query String, sometimes I saw in URL of facebook and twitter, what it is and why  is it used?

Please explain in detail. I query it most of time in google but have not found satisfactory results.

**I think it used in Ajax based framework.**

Comment: don't you think it is query string pasing 'q' parameter .. ? If you already know that then what do you want to know .. ?

Comment: It looks an empty string passed as the value for `q`, and a forward slash passed as the hash string.

Comment: it is value of q parameter .

Comment: As far as facebook's concerned it probably relates to google indexing -> https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Comment: and what it is **www.xyz.com/#/en/any.html**

Comment: @RahulMurari: It's the exact same, only with a slash instead of a bang

Answer (score 3):

It is for updating the page's URL without fully reloading the page. `/?q=` is just an empty variable in the query string. But, everything after a `#` is actually in the hash part of the URL. That was originally used to automatically scroll a page to an anchor (`<a name="blah">`). It is accessible via JavaScript, and because it doesn't reload the page, it is perfect for URLs that work when copy-pasted to the URL box, change when you do stuff on the page, but still keep everything loaded.

Shortly: `/?q=` is an empty variable in the query string, `#/` and everything after that is data for JavaScript to process. The slash(es) in the hash string make it look like it is also a part of the directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

Section 3 of [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-16) may be helpful.

The `/?q=` is a query string, where the parameter named `q` is blank/empty.

Everything after the `#` is called the fragment.  Sometimes it's used to jump to a bookmark on the page, but, usually it's just some data that the Javascript running in your browser can use.  If you change the part after `#` in the URL, your page doesn't reload, but, the Javascript in your browser can react to it.